# Aren't all sets in a topological space open??

Tags: general-topology

I have come across this exercise that asks me to prove the following 'theorem'
$$\underline{Theorem}. \text{A set U in a topological space is open if and only if for each}\  x \in U, U \ \text{contains a neighborhood of x}.$$
I'm very confused by this example because I thought that all the elements in a topology $\mathscr{T}$ are by definition open sets and thus any $U \in \mathscr{T}$ is open.  Am I missing something with problem?? I don't need any one to necessarily actually prove the theorem, right now I just want help understanding what it's stating. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When they say "set $U$ in a topological space", then mean an arbitrary subset, not necessarily "an element $U$ of the topology". There is a distinction between the topology and the topological space.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense.. Is that wording common? I have copied the question exactly, and the way it is read as is makes it seem as though $U \in \mathscr{T}$

Comment: The wording is definitely very common. Perhaps thinking of it as saying "A set $U$ of points in a topological space..." will make it a bit clearer what it's saying

Comment: Okay yeah that makes it more clear. Thank you!

Comment: remove removerem

Comment: An element of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is an element $x\in X$. An open set is a member of $\tau$, but we don't call open sets "elements of the topological space." So you are confusing two different notions in topological spaces.

Comment: It is in fact quite rare for people to refer to the set $\tau$ explicitly.  Far more common is to say '$U\subset X$ is open'.  We are interested in all sorts of other subsets of $X$ besides the open ones: closed sets, connected sets, compact sets and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's be more precise. A topological space is a pair $(X,\mathscr T)$ where $\mathscr T\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ has certain properties, and is called the "topology" of the space.

The above theorem is saying that:

> A set $U\subseteq X$ is in $\mathscr T$ if and only if, for all $x\in U$, there is a $V\in \mathscr T$ such that $x\in V\subseteq U$.

So the "elements of $U$" are elements of $X$, not elements of $\mathscr T$. And when we talk about the elements of a topological space, we mean the elements (or points) of $X$, not the open sets $\mathscr T.$